# What is the name of the effect where every other frame is dropped and the remaining frames are duplicated?

Tags: premiere, final-cut-pro-x, effects

What is the name of the effect where every other frame is dropped and the remaining frames are duplicated?

Like this...

```
ABCDEFG   // 1: original
ACEG      // 2: every other frame deleted
AACCEEGG  // 3: remaining frames duplicated
```

Does Final Cut have this feature?

If not, how do I do this?

Comment: Thank you. I found some nice tutorials on the subject when searching for "strobe effect"/"strobe filter". Please create an answer with this in it (rather than a comment) so that I can accept it as the correct answer. Thanks again.

Comment: In After Effects it's called posterize time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Back in the days of analog video, TBCs used to call that a strobe effect. It looks like Premiere has a strobe filter, but I don't know if it can be configured to do the freezing, instead of flashes.